# Integration of Pressure across Nozzle

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image][[image]]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyolG.jpg)Now, I have encountered a problem, I need to calculate the net Force in the $x$-direction. I want to calculate it through integrating the pressure field inside the nozzle. Assuming the exit of the nozzle has atmospheric pressure and assuming incompressible and inviscid (having no viscosity) flow inside the Nozzle.

I have made the integral of the pressure gradient in the $x$ direction to get the net force in that direction. But it give me a different answer from the control volume approach.

I have attached below a photo for the geometry of the nozzle and the [gauge pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement) field inside the nozzle, that I have used for the gradient to integrate across the volume of Nozzle.

For the $Fx$ I got:

$$Fx= \rho \ Q^2\left(\frac{1}{A_1}-\frac{1}{A_2}\right)$$

While using the control volume approach, I got:

$$\frac{1}{2} \rho \ Q^2 \left(\frac{1}{A_2^2}-\frac{1}{A_1^2}\right) A_1+\rho \ Q^2 \left(\frac{1}{A_1}-\frac{1}{A_2}\right)$$

I want to know why there is difference. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give description of terms: $\rho$, $Q$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ ?

Comment: Pressure acts normal to the nozzle surface.  Did you integrate the axial component of the normal pressure at the surface to get this force?

Comment: @ChetMiller I did so but through integrating the gradient to the pressure field in the x direction over the volume of the nozzle.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer rho is density , Q is flow rate ,A1 Area at inlet of Nozzle , A2 Area at outlet of nozzle

Comment: Let’s see the details.

Comment: @ChetMiller My Procedure was the following:

Comment: @ChetMiller My Procedure was the following: I take the derivative of the above Pressure field with respect to X: I got : dP(x)/dx= rho*Q^2*(A^-3)* dA/dX.    I integrated this expression across the volume I take an infinitesimal Volume: A(x) * dx  , I made integral of : dP/dx * A(x) *dx and the limit of integral from A1 to A2 . I got : rho *Q^2*(1/A1-1/A2)

Comment: The pressure also varies radially.